# Bootstrap modal - check values and if correct close modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to have a Bootstrap modal form.
I want to check the input values and close the modal only if they are OK.
How can I achieve this with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to check the input value first and if match close the modal using `$('#yourmodal').modal('hide');`

Example:

```
    if($('[name="test"]').val() == 'hello'){
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/46vhv7wz/7/